# Run background task in Android using MVVM pattern

Tags: mvvm, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I working on android app using `MVVM` pattern. I need to perform some background math calculations in my `ViewModel` class. This task will read some data from file `A` and then save results in few other files. And return an `Int` result when it's done to the `MainActivity`. My question is how can I achieve this? Searched a lot in the internet but with no success. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A background task in Android means that you want that task to execute when the application is in the foreground/background state. It also means that the task will be executed if the device has been rebooted, or the application has been closed/minimized. Work Manager class is perfect for such a purpose.